# Is there anyway to overcome thef potassium sorbate in apple cider to make it ferment

Tags: mead

I have 5 gallons of apple cider that I an trying to ferment with 10 lbs.of clover honey 3.5 lbs. brown sugar to make cyser.the OG is 1.172 PH 3.6 and I can't get to ferment!I found out there is potassium sorbate in it.Is there anyway to get it to ferment I have put a lot of money in it .Can anyone help me?

Comment: The 3.6pH probably isn't helping much either.

Comment: How much yeast have you added?  You need a lot of very active yeast to get something like this moving.

Comment: @brewchez 3.6pH isn't terrible for mead. That potassium sorbate, however, will definitely keep it from taking off (OP can get around this, as you posted in your answer). Also, the extremely high OG is enough by itself to stall most yeasts without a strong starter.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get that monster on a very active pitch of yeast.  I'd recommend getting a couple packages of yeast going in a gallon of wort.  Once its at its peak of activity I'd pitch it into this cider bomb.  If there is preservatives in your cider source, you can over come the preservative to an extent with a large pitch of ACTIVE yeast.

If you have a batch of beer that's done fermenting then rack the cider onto that cake and keep it warm 70-72F.

Comment: Fun fact, you can use this same technique to make wine from Mountain Dew (or any soda, really): https://www.homebrewsupply.com/learn/brew-the-dew-mountain-dew-wine.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have a stuck fermentation,  EC-1118 is your friend.  Like Brewchez suggested, get that stuff roaring, then toss it in.  EC-1118 will chew through damn near *anything* and will do it in a big damn hurry, too.  What you're left with will be dry and subtle flavors might not be as present as they'd be with a less vigorous fermentation, but it'll work, which is more than can be said about some of the other yeast strains that are usually great for cysers.